# Copy One Folder/Subfolder into Multiple Folders (Finder/Mac)

Tags: macos, finder

I have a situation where I need to copy the same folder and subfolder into multiple parent folders. For example: I have 100 folders named from Folder_001 to Folder_100; I need a Folder "A" with a sub folder "B" put into each of those 100 folders, so they all look like this:

```
Folder_001
 >A
  >B

Folder_002
 >A
  >B
```

etc. etc.

I'm working on a Mac with Finder, etc. Is there some way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done in Terminal. Suppose your 100 folders are on your Desktop, you would start the Terminal application and type this

```
cd Desktop && for f in Folder_*; do mkdir -p $f/A/B; done
```

If your 100 folders are in a folder called `Freddy Frog` in your HOME directory, you would do

```
cd "Freddy Frog" && for f in Folder_*; do mkdir -p $f/A/B; done
```

If you don't normally use Terminal, just hit `Cmd+Spacebar` and start typing `Terminal` till it guesses correctly and then hit `Enter`.